# $\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Calculate
$$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}dx.$$
I applied the formula that says : $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)$ but I do not think it helps me in some way.

Comment: The following may be helpful:$\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}dx^2}{x^2\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}$

Comment: Yes it is. I know how to solve it know.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompt:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int{\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^4+x^2+1}}\text{d}x}&=\int{\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}\text{d}x}
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}\text{d}x}+\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}\text{d}x}
\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left( x+\frac{1}{x} \right) ^2-1}}\text{d}\left( x+\frac{1}{x} \right)}+\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left( x-\frac{1}{x} \right) ^2+3}}\text{d}\left( x-\frac{1}{x} \right)}
\\
&=…
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Please read the Quality standards for this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards  -- the question you have answered is little more than a demand for an answer with minimal effort made.  The question should be improved before an answer is provided: this benefits the asker and the site as a whole.